# How to overwrite a view template from within a module?

Tags: views, theming, features

Till now I only used the theme folder to overwrite specific view templates. In order to be able to separate code from theming and bundle functionality I would like to put this view template into a custom module using features.

I guess there won't be a direct way to do this in features itself but that wont be the main problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the views template path directly within your module (following assumes views 2.x):

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_api().
 */
function mymodule_views_api() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule');
  return array(
    'api' => 2.0,
    'path' => $path,
    'template path' => $path . '/templates',
  );
}
```

Check out the API documentation built into views for adding templates into your module: http:///help/views/api-default-views (<-- requires advanced help module)